# Combinatorics on hotel vouchers problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, puzzle

I'm taking an online Discrete Mathematics course because I know it is very useful if you want to get into Computer Science.

This is the question I'm struggling with.

> You have vouchers for three hotels: A, B and C. You have 10 vouchers for hotel A, 15 vouchers for hotel B and 20 vouchers for hotel C.
>
> > There is one restriction though. You cannot sleep in one hotel for two nights in a row, so you must switch hotels every night. Is it possible to do this for 45 consecutive nights? 45 is the total amount of vouchers.

I know it is possible as the online professor proved it, but I was confused by his proof and didn't understand how he did it. Appreciate any explanations!

---

Edit: The professor simplified the vouchers for the different hotels since they were all divisible by 5. So hotel A had 2, B had 3, and C had 4.
He then put this pattern on the board "ACACBCBCB" and said 'repeat 5 times this path of length 9'. It works, but I'm confused on how he got there. The pattern came out of nowhere.

---

Edit: Thank you all so much on the help. I honestly should have thought about it harder before asking but I'm still super grateful for all the help in helping me understand.

Comment: It would help if you described the online proof and point out what you found confusing in it.

Comment: If you were asked to arrange $2$ As and $3$ Bs  and $4$ Cs would you find that a challenge that need explaining.  .... well, I'd so $2 + 3 = 5 = 4+1$ so if put the $A$s and $B$s together to make a strip of $5$ long and place a $C$ between each term we can do $ACACBCBCB$.

Comment: It often helps to work through a smaller version of problems.  What you found confusing about the solution by an "online professor" is not well enough described as yet for Readers to try to clarify.

Comment: When you say "the pattern came out of nowhere," are you referring to the 9-letter pattern "ACACBCBCB"?

Comment: Basically the "greedy" algorithm will work, so just use whichever other hotel you have the most vouchers of. This algorithm only fails if it is actually impossible to achieve, and this happens when one hotel has more vouchers than the other two combined plus one, cause then you cannot space out all the visits to that one hotel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to sleep in $C$ $20$ times, and you have to sleep in $A$ and $B$ a total of $25$ times, so you can’t simply alternate between $C$ and the others. If you could use up $5$ of the non-$C$ vouchers first, though, you could alternate the remaining $20$ of them with $C$ vouchers. And this is easy: start by using $BABAB$. You now have $8$ $A$ vouchers, $12$ $B$ vouchers, and $20$ $C$ vouchers, so you can finish with

$$\underbrace{CACA\ldots CA}_{8\times CA}\underbrace{CBCB\ldots CB}_{12\times CB}\,,$$

for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Not difficult:

CBCBCBCBCBCACBCACBCACBCACBCACBABCABCABCABCABC

In summary:  (CB) 5 times, (CACB) 5 times, (ABC) 5 times.

Comment: To explain my reasoning (a similar argument works for the solution you posted).  Get rid of a few C's and B's until there are 15 C's and 10 B's and 10 A's.  Now alternate:  CA, CB until you are down to 5 of each.  Then cycle through the remaining five of each.

Answer (score 0):

Just come up with *a* solution.

If you alternate $B$ and $C$ you can sleep at $B$ for one night and $C$ then next until you run out of your $15$ $B$ coupons and have $5$ unused $C$ coupons. But you can intersperse those with the $A$ coupons.  Until you $C$ coupons and have $5$ unused $A$ coupons.  But just intersperse those with the first bunch of vouchers.

So  Do $ABC$ five times to use up $5A$s, and $5B$s, and $5C$s.  Then to $BC$ ten times to use $5A$s, $15B$s (all), and $15 C$s.  Then the $AC$ five to to us up $10A$ and $15B$ and $20C$.

Or you can split the coupons into two sets.  One of $23$ nights and on of $22$ nights.  One has all the $B$s the other has all the $C$.  The $A$ are split but in the start of one and the end of the other.  So one set with is $BBBBB....BAAA$ and the other is $AAAAAAACCCC.....C$

So on night $2m +1$ you pick from set $1$ which will be $B$ if $m \le 20$ and $A$ if $m >20$.  And on night $2m$ you pick from set $2$ which will be $C$ if $m >7$ and will be $A$ if $m \le 7$.  The $B$ and the $C$ will never be concurrent as they are from different sets.  ANd the $A$s will never be concurrent as they are in different positions in the two sets.

Alternatively I might think:

First let's place the $C$.  Place them one apart.

$-C-C-C-........ -C-----$.

that fills up all the $2k$ for $k\le 20$.  In other words all the evens up to $40$.

Now place then $B$s but start from the other end.

$-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-CBCBC........ BCBCB-B-B$

That fills up all the odds from $45$ down to ... whatever $45-2*15$ is.... I guess that's $15$.

That leave just the odd numbers up to $15$ and the even numbers more than $40$.  Fill them in with $A$s.

$ACACACACACACACACACBCBC........ BCBCBABAB$

There are *many* ways to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

A more or less direct approach to solving the problem is to set out $20$ $C$'s with spaces between them for $A$'s and $B$'s.  Fill the first $15$ spaces with $B$'s and the final $4$ spaces with $A$'s. This leaves you with $6$ $A$'s. You can dispose of $2$ of them before the first and after the final $C$. The final $4$ $A$'s can go into some of the $CBC$'s.

The professor's approach sort of does the same thing with $2$ $A$'s, $3$ $B$'s, and $4$ $C$'s, except it look like they may have simply wedged the $4$ $C$'s in between a starting pattern of $AABBB$ (using the coincidence that $4=(2+3)-1$). The key thing, actually, is that the resulting $9$-character begins and ends with *different* letters, so that repeating the pattern doesn't violate the rule against consecutive letters being the same.